# Identifying a table on HTML

Tags: javascript

I would like to retrieve data from a html page. The data are in a table but unfortunately this table doesn't have id or name, the only thing I know a string which is in its rows. Is there any easy way how to  find that table? 
Thank you

Comment: Normally, you should use the DOM **write-only**. Can't you retrieve the data in the table where it was created, e.g. from the server?

Comment: Very possible.... what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can find all tables and then search for your string inside innerHTML: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/05faLxjt/

Comment: I am not very professional at Javascript, what I do in fact is to get some data into excel with vba, and I usually use the getElement(s)By... methods.  But when I don't have any identifiers I am have problems. Anyway, thanks for answers, I know now, where to start.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("table td").contains("my text")
```